# Finding a true integer square root from an array

Tags: arrays, ruby, iteration

I'm sure this is such a simple solution and for that I'm sorry but it's driving me mad.

I'm trying to iterate over an array and find a true integer square root and if there isn't one then square the number instead.

I don't know how to do Math.sqrt() and produce an integer not a float without making all results an integer. Can anyone help?

```
def square_or_square_root(arr)
  new_arr = []
  arr.each { |num|
    if (Math.sqrt(num)).is_a? Integer
      new_arr << Math.sqrt(num)
    else
      new_arr << (num * num)
    end
  }
  puts new_arr
end
```

Comment: If you are in no rush, you could do the following for your calculation for each element of the array. `def isr(n); 0.step { |i| case i*i <=> n; when 1 then break nil; when 0 then break i; end }; end; isr(121_104) #=> 348`.

Comment: imo, you should have simply asked how one can determine if an integer is a perfect square, and if it is, how it can be computed. Once that's known, iterating over the array is trivial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
def square_or_square_root(arr)
  new_arr = []
  arr.each do |num|
    if (Math.sqrt(num) % 1) == 0
      new_arr << Math.sqrt(num).to_i
    else
      new_arr << (num * num)
    end
  end
  puts new_arr
end
```

Comment: Better to use `#map`, I think. No need for `new_arr`.

Comment: Just wanted to keep code with minimum changes to satisfy the requirement.

Comment: Ah, gotcha, I totally should have seen that !way of determining whether a float is an integer value. So simple. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There's some structural problems here as well as some mathematical ones. First define a method that identifies squares:

```
class Integer
  def square?
    Math.sqrt(self).to_i ** 2 == self
  end
end
```

Then apply that to the problem. Using `map` avoids the `new_arr` mess, you can just transform this array directly:

```
def square_or_square_root(arr)
  arr.map do |num|
    if (num.square?)
      num
    else
      num ** 2
    end
  end
end
```

Then when you use it you get results like this:

```
square_or_square_root([ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 ])
# => [1, 4, 9, 4, 25, 36, 49, 64]
```

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't explain properly. I'm trying to find if each number contains an integer square root, such that 4 would return 2 and 9 would return 3.

Comment: You could adjust the code here to return the actual square root instead. Do you want to select only perfect squares from your list, or do you want to do that *and* return their square roots?

Answer (score 1):

`#sqrt` will always return a `Float` -- but does that float have an integer value? That's the question.

Think of a test for whether a `Float` represents an integer value.

Comment: This is more of a hint than an answer.

Comment: @tadman It depends whether the question is "give me teh codez" or "can you help me get to a solution?"

Comment: I think sufficient effort to solve the problem was demonstrated in the question. It wasn't a "plz halp" question, just a misunderstanding about the properties of square roots.

Comment: @tadman Well, I'll have to disagree there, because to me code like `(Math.sqrt(num)).is_a? Integer` indicates a misunderstanding about numeric types and other fundamentals in Ruby.

Comment: Not everyone is a CS or math major. I think being stumped about something is nothing to be ashamed of, we all have days like that.

Comment: @tadman Nobody mentioned shame. Being guided to think about classes should definitely be welcome, especially if a person didn't have that kind of technical education (I didn't). That aside, please don't guide people towards monkey-patching `Integer`.

Comment: One of the nice things about Ruby is you *can* patch in methods on Integer, and if you do it in a tactical and limited manner your code can become simple and self-explanatory. Normally I'd avoid this, but in this very particular example that's the best spot for the method, at least as far as Ruby is concerned.

Comment: You've hit the point I'm trying to find David, and I do appreciate you setting me challenge. I'll try and see if I can figure it out. @tadman I appreciate your responses also. I will admit to originally just looking for the answer as I was super stumped.

Comment: @tadman Then maybe leave add note to look into using a refinement in production code.

Comment: Patching Integer is entirely discretionary and if you or your company's coding practices disallow it, then that's fine, but it's highly situational. Refinements can be more confusing than a self-explanatory patch, but it's good to mention that as an option for organizing and containing things like this.

Comment: @haletothewood Thanks -- be super careful about Float-based multiplication and division also, as it can be imprecise. I think you'd be OK here because: `(1..100_000_000).to_a.select{ |x|  Math.sqrt(x).to_i ** 2 == x }.count == 10_000`

Answer (score 1):

The following code will give desired output. Here we're checking to see if the square root of a number `s` is an integer, if it is then its difference with `s.floor` will be `0`:

```
def square_or_square_root(arr)
  new_arr = []
  arr.each { |num|
    s = Math.sqrt(num)
    if (s - s.floor).zero?
      new_arr << s.to_i
    else
      new_arr << num * num
    end
  }
  puts new_arr
end

arr = [1,2,4,5]

square_or_square_root(arr)
#1
#4
#2
#25
```

You should probably use map here anyway

```
arr.map { |n| 
  s = Math.sqrt(n)
  (s - s.floor).zero? ? s.to_i : n.abs2
}

#=> [1, 4, 2 25]
```

Note: Just for variation I've used `Numeric#abs2` here to find the square. You can also use `Integer#**` i.e. `n ** 2`.

Comment: Nice use of `#zero?`

Comment: Agreed, nice solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
> (1..20).map {|e| (Math.sqrt(e).floor ** 2 == e) ? e.to_s : e*e }
=> ["1", 4, 9, "4", 25, 36, 49, 64, "9", 100, 121, 144, 169, 196, 225, "16", 289, 324, 361, 400]
```

I added the `.to_s` so you can see which `e` satisfies the condition of 
 `(Math.sqrt(e).floor ** 2 == e)`

The key element here is [Float#floor](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Float.html#method-i-floor) which returns the largest integer less than or equal to the float. You can achieve the same with `.to_i`